# How to use ECF JMS/ActiveMQ provider with remote services?

Tags: jms, osgi, activemq-classic, eclipse-ecf

In order to make an OSGI service to be remotely accessible, I'd like to use ActiveMQ JMS broker as a distribution provider inside ECF framework. Which steps should I take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be answering my own question in order to document it.

1. Get a minimal working ECF remote service workspace, with ecf.generic.server as the distribution and one of the discovery providers (zookeeper for example). You can use http://wiki.eclipse.org/EIG:Getting_Started_with_OSGi_Remote_Services tutorial.
2. Install an ActiveMQ broker with default configuration.
3. Download the JMS/ActiveMQ ECF providers from https://github.com/ECF/JMS. Add the `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.jms` and `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.jms.activemq` projects in your workspace, build and add them to your run configuration or target platform.
4. For the provider service properties, do the following changes:

   a. Change the `"service.exported.configs"` property for as `"ecf.jms.activemq.tcp.client"`

   b. Add `"ecf.endpoint.connecttarget.id"` property with the following value `"tcp://[ACTIVEMQ_IP]:61616/rs_topic"`, replacing [ACTIVEMQ_IP] with the broker IP. You can also change the topic name as something related to your service.
5. Now we also need a ActiveMQ JMS Server Container. Add the following code to the provider side. Use the Activator or fire up a new component with DS.  You can also get an `IContainerFactory` object from the service registry.

   > ```
   > IContainerFactory containerFactory = ContainerFactory.getDefault();
   > containerFactory.createContainer("ecf.jms.activemq.tcp.manager", 
   > new Object[] { "tcp://[ACTIVEMQ_IP]:61616/rs_topic" });
   > ```